# Export Blender models and (procedural) material to Browser?

Tags: blender, webgl, materials, browser-based-games, browser

Given that Verge3d cannot support Volume input, or volumetric shader property in the material output node. Using WebGl 2, and possibly 3.js, is it possible for me to export my blender models and their materials to a webpage/browser?  Will they show up in browse/web pages exactly as designed/seen in Blender viewport? Also, will such procedures apply to [procedural fire like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvbphr8EUYQ), too?

Comment: I don't know of a tool that will export Blender materials 1:1 for web applications. You may have to hand-code some WebGL shaders that do something equivalent.

Comment: I see. Do WebGL 2 shaders share the same color ramp as Blender? Also, do I need 3.js or Vue.js for web graphics as well? Or is 3.js optional?

Comment: Three/Vue/etc. are just libraries that make some things convenient for you. They don't do anything you can't do in your own code if you want to write all the boilerplate yourself. "Color ramp" isn't really a feature at the graphics API level that WebGL represents — it's something you'd implement in your shader.